# SQL - Record Between and On Two Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am writing query to check two dates between a date range. Basically its for Leave Application. If A user has record of leave application from '2017-07-13' to '2017-07-17', I want to forbid user to apply another leave application on these two dates as well as dates between these two dates (i.e. 14,15 & 16)

I have written following query, and tried make it successful but no luck. Thanks in Advance

```
SELECT * FROM `leaves` WHERE emp_id=8 AND from_date BETWEEN'2017-07-12' AND 
'2017-07-14' AND to_date BETWEEN '2017-07-12' AND '2017-07-14' AND 
status!='Rejected'
```

Table Data

```
| emp_id | from_date  | to_date    | status   |
|--------|------------|------------|----------|
| 8      | 2017-07-13 | 2017-07-17 | Approved |
| 8      | 2017-07-31 | 2017-07-31 | Pending  |
```

Sample Input (Output)

- from date = 2017-07-14 AND to date = 2017-07-16 (returns row one)
- from date = 2017-07-12 AND to date = 2017-07-14 (returns row one)
- from date = 2017-07-14 AND to date = 2017-07-18 (returns row one)
- from date = 2017-07-15 AND to date = 2017-07-15 (returns row one)
- from date = 2017-07-12 AND to date = 2017-07-12 (returns nothing)
- from date = 2017-07-18 AND to date = 2017-07-18 (returns nothing)

Comment: Types of `from_date` and `to_date` are `date`, right ?

Comment: I think you might need something like this - `from_date BETWEEN '2017-07-13' AND 
'2017-07-17' AND to_date BETWEEN '2017-07-13' AND '2017-07-17' `

Comment: No. Its `varchar` for some reason, but if solution works, I can make it `date`.

Comment: @ArunGeorge Actually 13 to 17 is a leave application already in table. If user tries to apply new leave between 12 to 14, I want to forbid him as 13-14 are days where leave is already applied.

Comment: To check for overlaps you need to apply this logic: `start1<=end2 and end1 >= start2`

Comment: @ZaheerAttar convert them to date. Always store correct data in correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `leaves`
WHERE emp_id=8 AND status != 'Rejected'
AND (
 (STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-07-10' AND '2017-07-15')
 OR (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-07-10' AND '2017-07-15')
)
OR (
 (STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-07-10')
 AND (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-07-15')
)
```

Comment: Actually 13 to 17 is a leave application already in table. If user tries to apply new leave between 12 to 14, I want to forbid him as 13-14 are days where leave is already applied.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive operator. And as leaves exists for 13 to 17, User should not be allowed to apply for 12 to 14 but he/she should be allowed to apply from 12 to 12, i.e. for one day.

Comment: `BETWEEN '2017-07-13' AND '2017-07-17'` doesn't look right. These dates are in table & not taken from Input. Input is '2017-07-12' & '2017-07-14'

Comment: Ok. Then you can try with those dates. Have updated answer.

Comment: Thanks.. Little Problem.. Query seems to doesn't work on dates like '2017-07-14' AND '2017-07-16'

Comment: Are you using some procedure or just select query?

Comment: Its Just `Select`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM leaves
WHERE emp_id=8 AND status != 'Rejected'
AND (
 (STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN'2017-07-14' AND '2017-07-16')
 OR (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017-07-14' AND '2017-07-16')
)
OR (
 from_date <= '2017-07-14' AND to_date >= '2017-07-16'
)` I have extended your query. It seems working fine, let me know if its efficient..

Comment: Please try with update answer. It's more efficient and works for all the ranges.

Comment: There's much more query here than is strictly necessary

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM leaves 
 WHERE emp_id = 8 
   AND status != 'Rejected' 
   AND from_date < '2017-07-16' 
   AND to_date > '2017-07-14'
```

Note that for the purposes of this query, it makes no difference whether you store a string or a date, as long as it's correctly formatted. But for other reasons you should always store data with the correct data type.

Also, you may wish to change one of the signs above (but probably not both) to <= or >=